# Merging row data using panda's in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a small python application that creates a csv file that contains data for a recipe system,

Imagine the following structure of excel data

```
Manufacturer    Product Data 1  Data 2  Data 3
Test 1  Product 1   1   2   3
Test 1  Product 2   4   5   6
Test 2  Product 1   1   2   3
Test 3  Product 1   1   2   3
Test 3  Product 1   4   5   6
Test 3  Product 1   7   8   9
```

When merged i woudl like the data to be displayed in following format,

```
Test 1  Product 1   1   2   3   0   0   0   0   0   0
Test 2  Product 2   4   5   6   0   0   0   0   0   0
Test 2  Product 1   1   2   3   0   0   0   0   0   0
Test 3  Product 1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

Any help would be greatfully recieved, so far i can read the panda dataset and convert to a CSV

Regards
Lee

Comment: would anyone be open to a private message to help further,  if i was to send an example spreadsheet that contains example data, as i am still struggling dispite the amazing help you guys are offering.

Answer (score 2):

Use melt, groupby, pd.Series, and unstack:

```
(df.melt(['Manufacturer','Product'])
  .groupby(['Manufacturer','Product'])['value']
  .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.tolist()))
  .unstack(fill_value=0)
  .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
  Manufacturer    Product  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0       Test 1  Product 1  1  2  3  0  0  0  0  0  0
1       Test 1  Product 2  4  5  6  0  0  0  0  0  0
2       Test 2  Product 1  1  2  3  0  0  0  0  0  0
3       Test 3  Product 1  1  4  7  2  5  8  3  6  9
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cols = ['Manufacturer', 'Product']
d = df.set_index(cols + [df.groupby(cols).cumcount()]).unstack(fill_value=0)
d
```

Gets me

```
                       Data 1       Data 2       Data 3      
                            0  1  2      0  1  2      0  1  2
Manufacturer Product                                         
Test 1       Product 1      1  0  0      2  0  0      3  0  0
             Product 2      4  0  0      5  0  0      6  0  0
Test 2       Product 1      1  0  0      2  0  0      3  0  0
Test 3       Product 1      1  4  7      2  5  8      3  6  9
```

Followed up wtih

```
d.sort_index(1, 1).pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(range(d.shape[1]), 1, False).reset_index())

  Manufacturer    Product  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0       Test 1  Product 1  1  2  3  0  0  0  0  0  0
1       Test 1  Product 2  4  5  6  0  0  0  0  0  0
2       Test 2  Product 1  1  2  3  0  0  0  0  0  0
3       Test 3  Product 1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

---

Or

```
cols = ['Manufacturer', 'Product']
pd.Series({
    n: d.values.ravel() for n, d in df.set_index(cols).groupby(cols)
}).apply(pd.Series).fillna(0, downcast='infer').rename_axis(cols).reset_index()

  Manufacturer    Product  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0       Test 1  Product 1  1  2  3  0  0  0  0  0  0
1       Test 1  Product 2  4  5  6  0  0  0  0  0  0
2       Test 2  Product 1  1  2  3  0  0  0  0  0  0
3       Test 3  Product 1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

---

With `defaultdict` and `itertools.count`

```
from itertools import count
from collections import defaultdict

c = defaultdict(count)
pd.Series({(
    m, p, next(c[(m, p)])): v
    for _, m, p, *V in df.itertuples()
    for v in V
}).unstack(fill_value=0)

                  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
Test 1 Product 1  1  2  3  0  0  0  0  0  0
       Product 2  4  5  6  0  0  0  0  0  0
Test 2 Product 1  1  2  3  0  0  0  0  0  0
Test 3 Product 1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

Answer (score 2):

With `groupby`

```
df.groupby(['Manufacturer','Product']).agg(tuple).sum(1).apply(pd.Series).fillna(0)
Out[85]: 
                         0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
Manufacturer Product                                              
Test1        Product1  1.0  2.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
             Product2  4.0  5.0  6.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
Test2        Product1  1.0  2.0  3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
Test3        Product1  1.0  4.0  7.0  2.0  5.0  8.0  3.0  6.0  9.0
```